Cross-compiling ROS2 : CMAKE is unable to find some of the mounted libraries
I'm trying to cross-compile ROS2 with CMAKE for Debian. As the official emulated cross-compiling tool got deprecated on the basis of "pay for support", I've tried the method linked in the thread ROS Discourse thread. (Thread) (Github)
The GitHub in question features cross-compilation instructions and scripts for Raspberry Zero, so I've been trying to change my CMAKE file accordingly for Raspberry Pi 4B, as well as adapting it for general purpose. I've also been developing a simple python script based on that project to automate the building to other platforms. This link has been helpful
However, CMAKE somehow cannot find the location of the (installed) libraries despite having specified supposedly appropriate options.
bashrc. :
export ROS_DISTRO=iron

export TOOLS=/usr
#again, make it extendible by changing the value with dpkg -L 

cross-colcon-build() {
    if [ ! "$(ls -A /home/develop/rootfs/)" ]; then
        echo "WARNING: Your rootfs directory is empty!"
        echo "    Please mount rootfs using e.g. 'sshfs -o follow_symlinks,allow_other -o cache_timeout=115200 pi@[raspberry_pi_ip]:/ /home/develop/rootfs'"
        echo "    or synchronize it with e.g. 'rsync -rLR --safe-links pi@[raspberry_pi_ip]:/{lib,usr,opt/vc/lib} /home/develop/rootfs'"
        echo "    Otherwise, the empty rootfs directory may cause your build to fail!"
        echo ""
    fi

    USERPATH=/home/develop/rootfs
    #extendible in the future

    export C_INCLUDE_PATH="\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include:\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf:\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"
    export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include:\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf:\
        ${USERPATH}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"

    colcon build \
        $@ \
        --merge-install \
        --cmake-force-configure \
        --cmake-args \
    --compile-no-warning-as-error\
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/develop/toolchain.cmake \
        -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
        -DTHIRDPARTY=ON \
        -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF \ 
    -DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=1
        
}


My toolchain.cmake file:
#This sucks
message("Toolchain file loaded with path: $ENV{TOOLS}")


# set from .bashrc
set(tools $ENV{TOOLS})
set(rootfs_dir /home/develop/rootfs/)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE aarch64-linux-gnu)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)


#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/develop/ros2_ws/install)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${rootfs_dir} /home/develop/ros2_ws/install)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${rootfs_dir})
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${rootfs_dir})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a72 -ftree-vectorize -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer")
# if 32 bit -latomic
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS= "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a72 -ftree-vectorize -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer")



## Compiler Binary 
SET(BIN_PREFIX ${tools}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu)
#SET(BIN_PREFIX ${tools}/bin/aarch64-none-elf)

SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${BIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${BIN_PREFIX}-g++ )
SET (CMAKE_LINKER ${BIN_PREFIX}-ld 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool LD" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_AR ${BIN_PREFIX}-ar 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool AR" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_NM {BIN_PREFIX}-nm 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool NM" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${BIN_PREFIX}-objcopy 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool OBJCOPY" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${BIN_PREFIX}-objdump 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool OBJDUMP" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_RANLIB ${BIN_PREFIX}-ranlib 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool RANLIB" FORCE)
SET (CMAKE_STRIP {BIN_PREFIX}-strip 
            CACHE STRING "Set the cross-compiler tool RANLIB" FORCE)

# ABOVE ADDED AS TEST
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(PYTHON_SOABI cpython-311m-aarch64-linux-gnu)


set(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR OFF)


However, the compilation stops at certain packages that cannot find their libraries despite
specifying SYS_ROOT, FIND_ROOT_PATH and additionally PREFIX_PATH if set.
CMake Error at /home/develop/rootfs/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/draco/draco-targets.cmake:83 (message):
  The imported target "draco::draco_static" references the file

     "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdraco.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/home/develop/rootfs/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/draco/draco-targets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.


It also complained about not being able to find pkg-config (also installed on Pi) but I've been unable to find it.
How do I make it able to find it? I'm not familiar that much with CMAKE, so the configuration might be off. The hacky solution might be to move the libraries to /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu or create a symlink to where they actually are,but I'm 99% percent sure that there's a better way to solve this.
So far I've tried:

Changing SYS_ROOT and FIND_ROOT_PATH paths
adding CMAKE_PREFIX
Copying the /usr/lib manually to avoid rsync-related issues with copying library structure
Browsing CMAKE's abysmal documentation

What are the differences between FIND_ROOT_PATH and SYS_ROOT? The description in the documentation is very ambiguous and sparse.

Turns out I have a bizzare issue where some of my Debian tarballs have been corrupted, and some files are/were missing. Apparently, my Eduroam (University Internet) blocks Debian and Ubuntu repositories for unknown reasons, as well as blocks Cloudflare's DNS. This was also messing with my Docker setup.
I cleared the apt-get cache with
apt-get clean , then reinstalled the packages.
apt-get install --reinstall libdraco-dev
(On a side note, I have no idea why would you possibly block debian and ubuntu repositories when you have Ubuntu LTS installed across the network... )
Edit: This is still an issue.
